# Storing references to HTML elements in JS, what's the convention?

Tags: javascript, dom

In my app.js file I do a lot of document.getElementById('some-element') calls. I think it would be more readable and maintainable to store the result of this call to a variable and then access the element through it whenever I need to. What's the common way to do this in vanilla JS so that they're available in all functions? Do I need to create global variables?

Comment: "*so that they're available in all functions*" - usually you don't need an element to be available in *all* functions, but only those that will use it. Which shouldn't be too many if your code has good separation of concerns, and they should be grouped together already. So put it only in the respective module's scope.

Comment: defining a class > init(){} +>  initialize a variable set to the the element >  then call the variable using this

Answer (score 2):

Just set it to a variable at the top level of your code

```js
const someElement = document.getElementById('some-element');

function firstFunction () {
    // access by using 'someElement'
}

function secondFunction () {
    // access by using 'someElement'
}
```